# Edit flag for users

Tags: feature-request, editing, flagging

I have seen several questions which are asked by users who does not know English very well, *(sometimes just bad, including myself)*. I want to propose an Edit flag, which users can raise to aware community to edit their posts when they feel, they should be edited.

I want to hear from the community about this feature.

---

Though the original question was quickly edited, here is an [example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/155018/revisions)

Comment: Just edit it yourself...?

Comment: Hmmmm... interesting, but the volume of edits on indecipherable posts suggests that people are irked by bad English to the point of fixing it themselves (that's what I do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *has* been proposed a few times in the past, and we've certain features [on the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks) that will hopefully work toward this end as well...

But really, if you see something wrong, the best way to make sure it gets fixed is to *dive in and fix it yourself*. Anyone can suggest an edit, and once you have 2K reputation points your edits will be visible without pre-approval. If **you** can't fix it yourself, assuming that someone else can is a pretty bad assumption - maybe someone can, but who says they want to?

Comment: "maybe someone can, but who says they want to?", good point. thanks